# How to build the program, so that DLLs won't be required at the location of EXE ( CodeBlocks )

Tags: c++, dll, exe, codeblocks, static-linking

I have, after some effort, successfully built a little piece of example code and make it run. I am using C++ in CodeBlocks 13.12 on a Win 7 x64 machine. The program makes use of wxWidgets and OpenGL libraries.

The problem is, that in order to make the EXE run successfully, I had to copy these DLL files to the location of EXE :

- wxbase30ud_gcc481TDM.dll
- wxmsw30u_core_gcc481TDM.dll
- wxmsw30u_gcc48.dll
- wxmsw30ud_core_gcc481TDM.dll
- wxmsw30ud_gl_gcc481TDM.dll

I would like to know **how to build the program ( what settings to change in project)** so that the EXE file will be able to run on its own ( and also on other machines ) - without "missing DLL" error messages ? It would be nice if answer could be general and useful as a reference in future, similar issues.

Comment: Google "static linking"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linker, you could add lines similar to this one:

```
-static wxbase30ud_gcc481TDM
```

However, this isn't terribly effective or good practice. Better would be to go ahead and include the dll's with your .exe, and simply supply a shortcut to your program that the user could move anywhere. This allows you to install and keep all your program files together, but still let the user only worry about one for the entire thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please expand your answer with some support for your claims that this is not terribly effective or a good practice ? And that it is better to include all dlls with .exe etc. Note that I am asking this as a beginner to software development, not because of distrust or anything =)

Comment: I can't find the original link about this - I have looked up this question before, because I had similar thoughts. This is about the closest I can find: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=72775

Comment: Thank you, if you come across the original link or equally good, please share it here =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like Enigma Box, which packs the DLLs into an exe and if you call LoadLibrary it will function as expected:

http://enigmaprotector.com/en/about.html

Some others exist like ILMerge or XBundler I heard as well... haven't used them though.  I heard DLLPack too.

Comment: ILMerge is only for .NET assemblies AFAIK.